# MS Access Converting from Run Time to accdb?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I was wondering if it was possible to convert a 2007 MS access runtime database (The one where you have to click the setup and install it) back to an accdb? I just want to do this as a way to back it up.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! You just have to rename the accdr back to accdb.